# Passing arguments in XML for android?

Tags: android, xml, media-player

Maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way, but I'm trying to have a function called playSong, and depending on the button pressed, I want to pass the parameter via xml to the playSong function so it can choose the correct song by resource id.

Is there a better way to accomplish this or is the way that I'm trying possible?

Comment: use ids to identify the buttons

Comment: What type of data you have in xml? A better explanation can help others help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing params inside your app, it's better to send a object directly. Since sending xml/json or other text format need to parse. 
In this situation, you can create a param class for Button and pass it to the playSong function. If you have to pass text or String, you can also take serialization to the object.

```
class ButtonParam{
    int id;
    // anything else.
}

ButtonParam param = new ButtonParam();
param.id = 3;
// set your param here.
mButton.setTag(param);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        ButtonParam p = (ButtonParam)view.getTag();
        // call you method.
        playSong(p);
    }
});
```